# Can't extract hyperlink from webtable using PowerQuery

Tags: excel, hyperlink, powerquery

I have issue with extract hyperlink using PowerQuery in excel 2013, why PowerQuery see "blank cells"?

If I use traditional Web Query in Excel and i check option in Navigator "Full Html Formating" its work, but in power query its not work.

Anyone have solution for my problem ?
I erased data from other columns, because its not needed
I tried using formula Text.FromBinary(Web.Contents(http://....)), but as result is receive a html source code. Maybe solution is how convert html code to table in PowerQuery?

[image: View from PowerQuery]

[image: View from browser]

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `Text.FromBinary` try `Web.Page`:

```
Source = Web.Page(Web.Contents("https://...")),
Data0 = Source{0}[Data],
```